# Usage of Resource Group

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group, azure-management-groups, azure-subscription

I am managing all my Azure infrastructure using `Terraform`. *So I can destroy module by module...*

I have created an hierarchy with several levels of `Management Group`. From Geographical Zones (*Europe, Americas, Asia, ...*) to environment (*production, staging, ...*)
Then I have `Subscription` for each Business Unit. Each BU could deliver from one to many applications. I am grouping all resources (`VNet`, `Route Tables`, `AKS`, `Load Balancer`, `Database`, ...) for each application in a single `Resource Group`. Meaning that for each BU with only 1 application (*almost all BU use case...*), I have a 1-to-1 relation between my `Resource Group` and my `Subscription`.

I know it's not a *problem* but I'm wondering if there is a solution to attach more value to the `Resource Group`. What kind of logic could I implement at that level while I have already split in Geographical Zones, Environment and Business Unit.

Do you see anything that could be relevant here to group resources? Or is that just a last layer that is not really needed in my case?

Thanks

Comment: This question is likely to get opinion-based answers and therefor is not a great fit for SO. Please refer to [ask].

Comment: On-topic: A resource group is a container that holds related resources for an Azure solution. The RG can include all the resources for the solution, or only those resources that you want to manage as a group. **You decide how you want to allocate resources to RGs based on what makes the most sense for your organization**. Source: [What is a resource group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/manage-resource-groups-portal#what-is-a-resource-group)

Comment: Sorry @rickvdbosch. You are true. I'm expecting an opinio here. Didn't realize it's not an appropriate usage of SO.
On-topic: yes, I know exactly what a RG is. I was looking for thoughts on the decision path to select which resources to put in, when the abovehierarchy has already covered most splitting.

Comment: Some elements of response : 1) versioning of your app, maybe you want v1 and v2 to co-live for a given period of time. It might be better in that case to have different RGs since components share different lifecycle. 2) You could also think of High Availability or Disaster Recovery strategies. Maybe you need some replication in another region/datacenter/AZ or you have a local blue/green architecture. 3) Considerations like RBAC or policies. 4) RG dedicated to non-functional reqs (monitoring, cybersec, ...)

Comment: Hi @Jul_DW. Thanks a lot for your answers.
1) I didn't though to this case, but that's an existing one. So thanks a lot!
2) I didn't detailled all layers, but HA, FT & DR are already covered using MG and deployments/backups to other regions.
3) Yes. I have though to this one, but didn't find any additional value in my specific use case. Thanks anyway.
4) Once again, I didn't gave all details, but NFR are already covered also, in dedicated subscription and shared accross all products.

Thanks a lot, you have given me a very good hint!